# Is there any synonym for the word Sword/Knife/Blade that starts with a V or W?

Tags: synonyms

As the title says i need a synonym or even something more "removed" that could mean something akin to a bladed weapon that starts either with a V or W.

Comment: Could you give some more context? _Why_ does it have to start with a v or w? Are you doing a crossword puzzle? Writing a story where you need the alliteration (and with what?)? Translating a story where there is already an alliteration with something (what?)?

Comment: Its a rather long explanation. I am going to create a unique item for a video game (Path of exile), unique items are items with preset values and special properties. The item i am trying to create is going to be a one handed blade weapon that i wanted to name "Vajura's wizard *****" where the **** is the missing word for a type of sword that starts with v or w. There is also flavour text that goes with it which i want to make in a similiar fashion. Here you can check the other items http://www.bluechipps.com/uniques/ you can see the flavour text of each item if you open the link from the name

Answer (score 2):

If you're looking for actual weapons, rather than a general name for a weapon, then https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Types_of_swords lists lots of different types of sword.  Some start with a V or W.

One which caught my eye, and which is popular in fiction, is the "Wakizashi", often referred to as a "Samurai sword".

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wakizashi

You could pursue this strategy with "Types of knife", "Types of blade" etc pages which probably exist on Wikipedia too.

Comment: A general name would be prefered but i might be able to use this thanks

Comment: Along those lines, there’s also the Mediaeval [voulge](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Voulge) or the Ancient Roman [verutum](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Verutum).